Schedule OI and dual status return
When filing as a dual status alien (with 1040NR as the return), how should  one respond to the tax residency question on the Schedule OI? (« List the foreign country in which you claimed residence for federal tax
purposes during the tax year. »)
Does one have to list « US, FOREIGN COUNTRY » (given that the question is  about the entire tax year), or just « FOREIGN COUNTRY » (given that 1040NR is for the non-residency part of the year)? Would be grateful for any pointers!

Are you sure you're dual-status? Is it because of First Year of Residency or First-Year Choice?

The instructions say:

List the foreign country in which you claimed residence for federal tax purposes during the tax year

"Foreign" means outside the US. So you do not need to list the US there.
